# PowerMock mock creation of new object of generic class

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I need to mock creation of two objects

```
Holder<MyClass1> h1 = new Holder<>();
Holder<MyClass2> h2 = new Holder<>();
```

I use Mockito and PowerMock

```
Holder<MyClass1> mock1 = PowerMockito.spy(new Holder<MyClass1>());
Holder<MyClass2> mock2 = PowerMockito.spy(new Holder<MyClass2>());

PowerMockito.whenNew(Holder.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock1);
```

How can I specify generic type to mock two different objects? I need 2 mock for my test. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use wildcard `'?'`, as:

```
 Holder<?> holder = new Holder<>();
 Holder<?> mock1 = PowerMockito.spy(holder);
 Holder<?> mock2 = PowerMockito.spy(holder);
 PowerMockito.whenNew(Holder.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock1);
```